# How do you initialize an array inside a while loop and define it outside?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, variables, jcombobox

I need to be able to assign an array to a .txt file so I need to reference  the variable "s" outside the while loop. Even after I define and initialize the variable I still get an error when I initialize in the while loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
 package vp.sga_form_generator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class GUI extends JFrame{
    public GUI() throws FileNotFoundException {

        super("SGA Form Creator - Viper Productions");
            setSize(1000,800);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(30, 2));

            //Opens File
            Scanner names = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

    //      String name1 = names.next();
            String[] s;
            while(names.hasNext()){
                s = {names.next()};
            }

            JComboBox names1 = new JComboBox(s);
            JComboBox names2 = new JComboBox(s);

            add(names1);
            add(names2);


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use an array? The array will never have more than one value using this code, just use a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. {names.next()}; is only allowed when you initialize a String[] so you can 
   say something like String[] s = {"bla","bli","blu"}
2. The problem is that String[] is not initialized
3. You can not init the String with the appropriate size sinze you dont know it. 
   So String[] is not the structure of choice
4. If you need to use String[] then you must do generate a second String[] and copy back and forth each time you add one element.

Comment: Yes That is What I want

Comment: If I were to use ArrayList what would I do?

Comment: Also, Can you assign an ArrayList to populate a JComboBox?

Comment: This is My New code but now I get an error when I try to add it to the JComboBox.   ArrayList Aname;
   while(names.hasNext()){
       Aname.add(names.next());
   }
   
    
   JComboBox names1 = new JComboBox(Aname);
   JComboBox names2 = new JComboBox(Aname);

Comment: @user2455722 YOu need to initialize the `Aname` instace before using it. like `ArrayList <String> Aname = new ArrayList <String>();`

Comment: @user2455722 Thats was before I read your whole coment. try using `JComboBox names1 = new JComboBox(Aname.toArray());`. I hope this will help.

Comment: @user2455722 If this answer helped you then accept the answer and close the question.. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: My Problem now is that the JComboBox only comes up with 8 choices, even when i make more in the file.